# Joint probability distribution discrete random variables. Marginal distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions

Let X and Y be discrete random variables with joint probability mass function;
 P(X = x,Y = y) = 2x + y/12 ,
 for (x,y) = (0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(1,3)
 0, elsewhere 
Determine the marginal probability function of X and show that it is a probability function.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This is very similar to your other problem.  Make your table.  Verify that it is a probability function by showing that the entries in the table all add up to a total of $1$.  Find your marginal probability function by adding subtotals to columns or adding subtotals to rows (*depending on which way you oriented your table*).

Comment: Also... you should be more careful with how you type things  `2x+y/12` reads like $2x + (\frac{y}{12})$, not as $\frac{(2x+y)}{12}$

Comment: I have been able to fix them into a table but after I drew the table, I did not get exactly 1. For both problems when I add their marginal totals. I got figures close to 1 instead but not 1 itself

Comment: "*I did not get exactly 1*"  Show your work and show us what you *did* get.  Note, $\frac{1}{12}\approx 0.083$ but only approximately.  It can be helpful to keep things as fractions.  If your error is like how someone might think that $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}$ is not equal to $1$ simply because $0.33+0.33+0.33=0.99\neq 1$... then you really need to stop whatever bad habit is causing that.

Comment: I kept them as fractions and had 49/48 which is equivalent to 1.020...

Comment: Then you have an arithmetic error somewhere.  $((2\cdot 0 + 1) + (2\cdot 0 + 2)+(2\cdot 1+2)+(2\cdot 1+3))/12 = (1+2+4+5)/12=12/12=1$.  I have no idea why you got a denominator of $48$ when every fraction involved had a denominator of twelve...